# What's a "pp wave of death"?

Tags: general-relativity

What's a ["pp wave of death"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime)?
I've heard about them a few times but I don't really understand what they are.

Comment: Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime "the wave of death is a gravitational plane... which propagates through an initially flat spacetime, progressively destroying the universe" ("pp" stands for plane-fronted waves with parallel propagation ).

Comment: I had never heard of this. [A 2005 forum post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/wave-of-death.93654/); [Wikipedia on gravitational plane waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime).

Comment: Please don't make trivial two-character edits. If you would like to boost the visibility of an old question, you can offer a bounty.